# In Peoplesoft 8.5X Query Manager, Is there a way to default EMPID in filter criteria based on employee sign in?

Tags: sql, peoplesoft

I want to dynamically create a filter criteria in PS query manager which automatically picks EMPID value based on employee sign in ID. Is it feasible in Peoplesoft 8.5X ?

I am a beginner to Peoplesoft query creation. I have not tried anything yet.

SELECT A.EMPLID FROM PS_JOB A WHERE A.EMPLID = 'XXXX'

The above mentioned SQL should automatically replace XXXX with the sign in ID of the employee.

For Eg. If my user sign ID is 1234 and am running the query in query viewer, then SQL should be like

SELECT A.EMPLID FROM PS_JOB A WHERE A.EMPLID = ''1234''

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`%EmployeeID` metaSQL does not work in PSQUERY, but `%OperatorID` does.

Add criteria, select OPRID field, equals and expression and in the expression type `%OperatorID`

```
SELECT A.EMPLID
  FROM PS_JOB A, PSOPRDEFN B
  WHERE ( A.EMPLID = B.EMPLID
     AND B.OPRID = %OperatorID )
```